# "Unsupported action method signature". FolioReader Swift , Error

Tags: swift, xcode, filereader, epub

please help me to solve this error using FolioReaderKit Swift
[image]enter image description here

[image]

Comment: thank you for your Answer but still same issue occur , please help me

Comment: FolioReaderKit is an archived repository meaning that it is no longer supported by the original maintainer. As far as I am aware it uses UIWebView which has been deprecated and can no longer be used in an iOS app. The scope of fixing this is beyond a SO question, as it would require rewriting the dependency to use WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same crash while using Folioreader in my app. I have fixed it by doing below changes in my code.

In FolioReaderAudioPlayer.swift file. Update these 5 methods.

```
 @objc func pause() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        playing = false

        if !isTextToSpeech {
            if let player = player , player.isPlaying {
                player.pause()
            }
        } else {
            if synthesizer.isSpeaking {
                synthesizer.pauseSpeaking(at: .word)
            }
        }
        return .success
    }

    @objc func togglePlay() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        isPlaying() ? pause() : play()
        return .success
    }

    @objc func play() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        if book.hasAudio {
            guard let currentPage = self.folioReader.readerCenter?.currentPage else { return .commandFailed }
            currentPage.webView?.js("playAudio()")
        } else {
            self.readCurrentSentence()
        }
        return .success
    }

  @objc func playPrevChapter() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        stopPlayerTimer()
        // Wait for "currentPage" to update, then request to play audio
        self.folioReader.readerCenter?.changePageToPrevious {
            if self.isPlaying() {
                self.play()
            } else {
                self.pause()
            }
        }
        return .success
    }

    @objc func playNextChapter() -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus {
        stopPlayerTimer()
        // Wait for "currentPage" to update, then request to play audio
        self.folioReader.readerCenter?.changePageToNext {
            if self.isPlaying() {
                self.play()
            }
        }
        return .success
    }
```