# swift: EXC_BAD_ACCESS with using Realm and FolioReaderKit

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I installed FolioReaderKit using Cocoapods to read epub book. I'm trying to highlight text and add it to a list of highlights. But when I do this I get this error and my app crashes:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x41c4a1c96ae55d46)

line:

```
value = RLMGetOptional(static_cast<RLMOptionalBase *>(object_getIvar(obj, prop.swiftIvar)));
```

in `RLMAccessor.mm`:

```
id RLMAccessorContext::propertyValue(__unsafe_unretained id const obj, size_t propIndex,
                                     __unsafe_unretained RLMProperty *const prop) {
    // Property value from an NSArray
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(objectAtIndex:)]) {
        return propIndex < [obj count] ? [obj objectAtIndex:propIndex] : nil;
    }

    // Property value from an NSDictionary
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
        return [obj objectForKey:prop.name];
    }

    // Property value from an instance of this object type
    id value;
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:_info.rlmObjectSchema.objectClass] && prop.swiftIvar) {
        if (prop.array) {
            return static_cast<RLMListBase *>(object_getIvar(obj, prop.swiftIvar))._rlmArray;
        }
        else if (prop.swiftIvar == RLMDummySwiftIvar) {
            // FIXME: An invalid property which we're pretending is nil until 4.0
            // https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5784
            return NSNull.null;
        }
        else { // optional
            value = RLMGetOptional(static_cast<RLMOptionalBase *>(object_getIvar(obj, prop.swiftIvar)));
        }
    }
    else {
    // Property value from some object that's KVC-compatible
        value = RLMValidatedValueForProperty(obj, [obj respondsToSelector:prop.getterSel] ? prop.getterName : prop.name,
                                             _info.rlmObjectSchema.className);
    }
    return value ?: NSNull.null;
}
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It doesn't appear that FolioReaderKit has been updated or touched in almost 4 years so it's likely it won't be compatible with newer versions of Realm. That being said, you may have outdated pods `pod update` or an outdated cocoapods `pod --version` or even incompatible versions of XCode - or perhaps the podfile is not configured correctly. Please check those items and perhaps include the podfile in the question. Also, I assume this `RLMAccessor.mm` is not your code but from the FolioReaderKit library? Can you clarify?

Comment: @Jay Yes, `RLMAccessor.mm` is not my code, but code from the FolioReaderKit library. I tried to update Realm and used different versions. It didn't help me. I am getting more errors.

Comment: Understood. This site, SO, is for assistance the code *you* wrote and not for help with troubleshooting third party libraries. Attempting to troubleshoot a library, even with all of the source code, goes well beyond what we can do here. I suggest reaching out to the developer of that library for assistance and compatibility information.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is asking for help troubleshooting a third party library which goes beyond what can be done on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Jay In my pod file I use only this code `pod 'FolioReaderKit'` and FolioReaderKit automatically install Realm version 3.13.1 So I'm trying to solve a problem with the current code. And I checked when I highlight the text my app write but not save in array. And I don't understand where it gets lost. I've noticed that people have recently asked other questions related to FolioReaderKit. And I think that they solved this problem. So I hope they check my question. So I don't want to close it.

Comment: I understand. We cannot fix a third party library; this `Realm version 3.13.1` is from 6 years ago and is a depreciated version of Realm that is no longer supported; the current version is 10.x and they are not backward compatible. Additionally, while there are a number of questions hereon SO about that library, I am not seeing any real solutions. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138232/unsupported-action-method-signature-folioreader-swift-error) and the comments regarding `UIWebView`. It seems it would take a major re-write to correct these issues.